# installing MVC 3 with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to install MVC 3 with visual studio 2010. I am using "Web plateform installer" and selected asp.net MVC 3, it showed message that MVC 3 installed successfully but It is not installed. I tried to launch Web plateform installer from asp.net/mvc3 but still same issue. I downloaded offline installer from:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491

AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe  21.6 MB

but it starts installing and then rolls back. Any suggestion please ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Does this folder exist: `\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET`?

Comment: i think you should update visual studio 2010 or resetup it , and install mvc3 through web platform installer again .